# Reads a file but prints integers that are not in the read file

Tags: c++, arrays

I am having trouble getting a file to read and then print a list to another file, line by line of the number of occurrences of each.

I works, however it prints the numbers: 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5 to the output file which are not in the read file

The struct:

```
struct entry {
string word;
string word_uppercase;
int number_occurences;
```

};
    `//for array

    entry myEntryArray[MAX_WORDS];

    int addNewEntryHere=0; //next empty slot`

My main calls extractTokensFromLine to read and put in an array:

```
void extractTokensFromLine(std::string &myString) {
    const char CHAR_TO_SEARCH_FOR = ' ';
    stringstream ss(myString);
    string tempToken;
    //Extracts characters from is and stores them into str until the delimitation character delim is found
    while (getline(ss, tempToken, CHAR_TO_SEARCH_FOR)) {
        processTokenArray(tempToken);
    }   
}
```

It goes through each line word by word to put in an array:

```
 void processTokenArray(string &token) {
    //temp uppercase for compare
    string strUpper = token;
    toUpper(strUpper);
    //see if its already there
    for (int i = 0; i < addNewEntryHere; ++i) {
        if (strUpper == myEntryArray[i].word_uppercase) {
            //yep increment count
            myEntryArray[i].number_occurences++;
            return;
        }
    }
    //nope add it
    myEntryArray[addNewEntryHere].word = token;
    myEntryArray[addNewEntryHere].number_occurences = 1;
    myEntryArray[addNewEntryHere].word_uppercase = strUpper;

    //where next place to add is
    addNewEntryHere++;
}
```

It then writes the Array to a file (each word and its number of occurrence):

```
bool writeArraytoFile(const std::string &OUTPUTFILENAME) {
    fstream outfile;
    if (!openFile(outfile,OUTPUTFILENAME,ios_base::out))
        return false;
    int var;
    for (var = 0; var < addNewEntryHere; ++var) {
        string word = myEntryArray[var].word;
        if(word != " " && word != "")
            outfile<<myEntryArray[var].word << " " <<IntToString(myEntryArray[var].number_occurences)<<std::endl;
    }
    closeFile(outfile);
    return true;
}
```

The Read File is TestData.txt:

I think I should like a bit of butter
And If its not
too much trouble some toast as well. And while you are in the kitchen a brace of expressos for me and my man here.

My Output file (sorted using the following method):

```
void sortVector(sortOrder so = NUMBER_OCCURRENCES) {
    bool shouldSwap = false;
    for (int var = 0; var < addNewEntryHereV; ++var) {
    for (int var1 = var+1; var1 < addNewEntryHereV; ++var1) {
        switch (so) {
            case ASCENDING:
                shouldSwap =!compareAscendingV(myEntryVector, var, var1);
                break;
                //TODO handle the following cases appropriately
            case DESCENDING:
                shouldSwap =!compareDescendingV(myEntryVector, var, var1);
                break;
            case NUMBER_OCCURRENCES:
                shouldSwap =!sortbyOccurrenceV(myEntryVector, var, var1);
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
            if (shouldSwap){
                std::string tmp = myEntryVector._V.at(var);
                myEntryVector._V.at(var) = myEntryVector._V.at(var1);
                myEntryVector._V.at(var1) = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Actual Output:

And 3
4 2
of 2
a 2
I 2
here. 1
man 1
my 1
me 1
for 1
expressos 1
brace 1
kitchen 1
the 1
in 1
are 1
you 1
while 1
well. 1
as 1
toast 1
some 1
trouble 1
much 1
too 1
5 1
3 1
2 1
1 1
not 1
its 1
If 1
butter 1
bit 1
like 1
should 1
think 1

Any sort of suggestion would be greatly appreciated, 
thanks

Comment: What is the actual problem? What does the output actually look like? What should the output look like instead?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything very wrong with the posted code. There can't be a lot of code left that you didn't post. So I would post the complete program, you'll get an answer very quickly then.

Comment: The actual problem is that the Output file is giving me numbers where there are no numbers in the Read file.  It should look like a list of words with the # of times they occur

Comment: Can you post what data type you're using for myEntryArray, including the struct/class definition for its entries?

Comment: Post a sample of the output.

Comment: The problem is in the part which is not posted.

Comment: I just posted a sample of the output and the struct as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your specification was not clear to me in some cases so I guessed. This should be pretty close to what you are trying to do.

gcc 4.7.3: g++ -Wall -Wextra -std=c++0x word-freq.cpp

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

typedef std::map<std::string, int> histogram_t;

std::string to_lower(const std::string& s) {
  std::string r(s);
  std::transform(std::begin(r), std::end(r), std::begin(r), ::tolower);
  return r; }

histogram_t word_freq(std::istream& is) {
  histogram_t m;
  std::string s;
  while (is >> s) { ++m[to_lower(s)]; }
  return m; }

void outAscWord(std::ostream& os, const histogram_t& m) {
  for (const auto& e : m) {
    os << e.first << " " << e.second << "\n"; } }

void outDescWord(std::ostream& os, const histogram_t& m) {
  for (auto i = m.crbegin(); i != m.crend(); ++i) {
    os << i->first << " " << i->second << "\n"; } }

template <class A, class B>
std::pair<B, A> flip_pair(const std::pair<A, B>& p) {
  return std::pair<B, A>(p.second, p.first); }

template <class A, class B>
std::multimap<B, A> flip_map(const std::map<A, B>& m) {
  std::multimap<B, A> r;
  std::transform(m.begin(), m.end(), std::inserter(r, r.begin()), flip_pair<A,B>);
  return r; }

void outAscCount(std::ostream& os, const histogram_t& m) {
  auto mm = flip_map(m);
  for (const auto& e : mm) {
    os << e.first << " " << e.second << "\n"; } }

int main() {
  // Can pass fstreams instead of iostreams if desired.
  auto m = word_freq(std::cin);
  outAscWord(std::cout, m);
  outDescWord(std::cout, m);
  outAscCount(std::cout, m);
}
```

Comment: @Ninja_the_Swift, can you post your entire program?

Comment: I read up more on maps and templates and they seem to be efficient for both small and large amounts of data.  Also I found that I had another Test File for reading under the same that was under the debug folder and it had those random numbers in there.  Eclipse copied it from the debug to under the general project folder and made it somewhat askew (my guess is that the IDE bugged out).  It is working now.  I greatly appreciate your suggestions.